# Definir uma questão editada pelo bot como duplicata

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas, perguntas-sem-resposta

O bot "Comunidade ♦", cavucou e colocou em destaque essa pergunta: [Como usar URLs diferentes e pegar informações delas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66168/como-usar-urls-diferentes)

Pelo que entendo e a maioria deve saber, o bot evidencia questões que ficam sem resolução.

Ok, a dúvida que tenho é, posso marcar essa questão como duplicada e apontar para uma questão sobre URL amigável?

Aliás, não precisa ser eu.. pode ser qualquer um com permissões para tal.

Comment: Se achares que há outra pergunta que responde a essa marca como duplicada sim. Aí vai para análize e caso seja duplicada fecha-se.

Comment: Relacionado: [Fechar a pergunta mais antiga como duplicata ou não?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3874/3117)

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei diversos mas cada uma tinha uma peculiaridade que não se encaixava perfeitamente. Então até o momento acredito que não encontrei uma duplicata. Mas também não fiz uma pesquisa muito profunda. Foi algo bem informal e superficial.

Answer (score 1):

Enquanto não tem 3k, é só clicar no link "sinalizar" abaixo da pergunta e escolher
 *"deveria ser fechada >> duplicata >> (colocar link da duplicata)"* :

[image]

Encontrei uma [*potencial duplicata*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27534/passando-vari%C3%A1veis-pela-url-utilizando-url-amig%C3%A1veis-via-get) fazendo uma busca pelas tags [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) e [url-rewrite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewrite).

Talvez merecesse um título mais enxuto ou descritivo que *Passando variáveis pela URL utilizando URL amigáveis via GET*, mas não consigo pensar em um... o bom é que duplicatas são para isso mesmo, vários títulos, uma única solução.

Primeiro, tinha pensado em colocar uma recompensa em [Como usar URLs diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66168/201) mas antes de gastar meus pontos mágicos decidi procurar e achei a tal outra.

Comment: Preguiça aqui... se o caro leitor animar de fazer um *bug report*, como bem se pode observar, a tradução desses 3 primeiros items das sinalizações tá zicada...